# How to show all Azure logs in Log Stream

Tags: azure, docker, logging

I've noticed that Azure's log stream will not actually show all logs for a given period if the logs go over a certain amount of lines (from what I've seen, roughly 6,000 lines). What if I have millions of users on my app, and I want to log each request? The logs will barely be able to show any of the requests except for the most recent ones.

And if I go to the left blade under Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go -> then click on `Current Docker logs (Download as zip)` it shows what is in the log stream (which is limited to 6k lines).

Why is Azure not storing *all* the logs, and how can I ensure that they are stored properly for a given time period? For example, in Monitoring > App Service logs I set the `Retention Period` to 20 days, thinking it would store the logs for 20 days. How can I actually store the logs for 20 days, no matter the length of the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is Azure not storing *all* the logs, and how can I ensure that
> they are stored properly for a given time period?

By default, Log stream is used to get the logs of your Azure app that is currently running and it stores the logs in Azure File system based on the retention period you assign to the App service logs. If you do not select the Application logging to file system by default the Application diagnostics logs are not deleted. refer below:-

[image]

In order to access these diagnostics logs and store them. You need to enable Diagnostic Settings and store your Logs in either Azure Storage account or send it to Azure Log analytics workspace like below:-

***Visit your Azure App Service > Diagnostic settings > Add diagnostic setting***

[image]

***Click Add diagnostic setting > And select the App service logs you need to store or send to Log analytics workspace or storage account or both:-***

[image]

***Send logs to Log analytics workspace :-***

[image]

*And query logs from the App service Log tables like below:-*

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs
```

[image]

```
AppServiceConsoleLogs
```

[image]

```
AppServicePlatformLogs
```

[image]

***Send logs to Azure storage account keep the retention days to 0 if you want to retain the logs forever or keep it to the desired days you want to retain the logs. You can store logs to storage account and also send it to Log analytics workspace like below:-***

[image]

[image]

Retrieved the logs in my storage account like below:-

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Enable diagnostics logging - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)